# rrdtool update error (nan)

Tags: awk, rrdtool

As the title above, i want to store a multiple data inside rrd database so that later can execute a temperature graph out of it.

My database named rn23.rrd

When i using awk command:

`` echo  rrdtool update rn23.rrd `/ops/bin/finf  | awk '$1 == "rn23" { print $2 ":" $11 }'` ``

the output is:

`rrdtool update rn23.rrd 1491273800:48`

then, i remove the "echo" to update the data inside rn23.rrd:

`` rrdtool update rn23.rrd `/ops/bin/finf  | awk '$1 == "rn23" { print $2 ":" $11 }'` ``

but when i try to fetch the data again using :

`rrdtool fetch rn23.rrd MAX --start 1491210243 --end now`

the result show this:

`1491270300: -nan
1491270600: -nan
1491270900: -nan
1491271200: -nan
1491271500: -nan
1491271800: -nan
1491272100: -nan
1491272400: -nan
1491272700: -nan
1491273000: -nan
1491273300: -nan`

Do any you guys know why it only recognized the timestamp but not the temperature? And how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the structure of your RRD -- IE, how you defined it, the DS and RRA definitions -- it is impossible to be certain, but I'm fairly sure you have a basic misunderstanding of how RRDTool works.

RRDTool is not a relational database that stores a set of records exactly as you provide them.  Instead, it does several additional consolodation steps before storing:

- Data normalisation
- Calculation of rates
- Consolodation into RRAs

These can adjust your data in ways you may not expect.  The main one is the second step, which *requires at least two normalised data points* to complete.

When you call `rrdtool fetch` you are actually querying the RRA, and if there are not yet enough data going in the start of the chain, you're not going to have anything in the RRA yet.

With only one data sample, you are unlikely to have even one complete PDP (primary data point) and even if you have, you may not have a CDP (consolodated data point) in your RRA as yet, depending on your RRD interval size and the number of PDP in a CDP in your smallest defined RRA.

If this is a bit much for you, then there is an excellent set of tutorials here by Alex of the hard-to-spell surname:
http://rrdtool.vandenbogaerdt.nl/

The TLDR is: give it more datapoints!  Submit at least 3 sample spaced at the RRD interval (600s?); from your posting, I am guessing you have a 300s interval and a 1cdp=1pdp RRA defined, but if your interval is 60s you may need 7 or more at 60s spacing.  Then you'll start to see consolodated datapoints appearing in the RRA.